# Having one insert happen during page rendering

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am currently working on a code that does a basic input before anything happens. This is so that it inserts something into the db so I can pull that ID and insert upon that ID. This creates an auto save type of insert.

I have some rendering calls within my page to make sure information is submitted correctly, and find myself having an issue with the rendering and input, as the rendering will cause the insert to be called twice, and not redirect the page. Any idea how I could get this insert to call once, and for the code to run as expected?

```
    /*
        NEW RECORD
    */
    // if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
    else
    {

                // insert null into database to create the save point
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test_table (name, email, notes) VALUES ('x', 'x', 'x')"))
                {
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                // show an error if the query has an error
                else
                {
                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare Auto-Save SQL statement.";
                }

                // gets id of null insert to update upon.
                $as_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
                printf ($as_id);

        // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            // get the form data
            $name = htmlentities($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $email = htmlentities($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $notes = htmlentities($_POST['notes'], ENT_QUOTES);

            // check that name, email are not empty.
            if ($name == '' || $email == '')
            {
                // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                renderForm($name, $email, $notes, $error);
            }
            else
            {
                // insert the new record into the database
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE test_table SET name=?, email=?, notes=? WHERE id=?"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $email, $notes, $as_id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                // show an error if the query has an error
                else
                {
                    echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
                }

                // redirect the user
                header("Location: view.php");
            }           
        }
        // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
        else
        {
            renderForm();
        }
    }

    // close the mysqli connection
    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the PHP manual page for header(), here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

Also, really your insert should be happening only when all of the validation has passed. In your script there is really no reason for it to be happening before this, unless you eventually intend to pass $as_id into renderForm() -- for example, to allow peripheral forms to save relational data before the core record is populated, but this is a bad pattern to follow.

As your code stands, your insert happens BEFORE the form is rendered, and again AFTER the form is submitted. And again every time the user fails validation and re-submits the form.

That said, you could probably get the result you need by swapping out this:

```
printf ($as_id);
```

With something like this:

```
header('Location: view.php?id='.$as_id);
```

Though, realise that doing this, you would never hit the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` -- I'm assuming you have this code block duplicated outside of your "NEW RECORD" condition, perhaps in an "EDIT RECORD" condition or similar.

Ideally you'd want to abandon this approach altogether though, in favour of an MVC-style architecture with RESTful routes...